# What is this function? Symmetrical around the x=y, asymptotes on the x and y

Tags: functions

I'm trying to determine the relationship between two (empirical) variables - let's call them 'a' and 'b'. I can see that the curve they trace out is symmetrical around the line y=x, and that the function has identical asymptotes at x=0 and y=0. There should be a relationship between these two variables that invokes no 'magic numbers', and I'm sure whatever it is will make profound physical sense. But I'm stumped to figure it out, and none of my usual approaches have helped.

Does anyone recognise this function on sight? Also, more generally, what is the proper approach to analyse curves of this kind?

For those curious, the data reflects the conductive solution for an internally heated annular wedge, where 'f' is the ratio of inner to outer lengths and 'phi' is the thermal flux.

[The function in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSi8H.png)

Comment: Perhaps you can try multiplying the two values together? I mean, to plot $f \cdot \phi_q$ ... Or add some powers to those? And then see what kind of graphs those give.

Comment: What's the physical meaning of the variables?

Comment: 'f' is the ratio of inner and outer lengths of a wedge of an annulus, and phi double prime is the second derivative of thermal flux. It's a model of a planet warmed by radioactive decay from inside the mantle, before the onset of convection.

Comment: This looks like a square hyperbola like $x^{-1}$.